# TFS working folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2015

we are moving from visual studio 2013 to visual studio 2015, and it is necessery for us to work with both studio in the same folders. Is there a way to use that and how can I set the tfs to work with both visual studios

Kind regards and thank you in advance

Comment: When you mention "necessary for us to work with both visual studios in the same folder" does the same folder mean the folder where your source code is kept? If so then I don't think you need to do anything special.

Comment: What issue did you get when you mapping TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you install both VS2013 and VS2015 on your machine. When you map a project from TFS to local path in VS2013, if you open VS2015, and select the workspace you create in VS2013, then you'll see the same local path in VS2015, you don't need to map it again (make sure your project can work in both VS2013 and VS2015):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to not do that as you might end up seriously corrupting the workspaces. Can you explain a bit more on why is this so necessary? I have helped organizations migrate between various instances of TFS over the few years now and we have not faced a situation like this. If you explain your particular use case a bit more I can perhaps suggest an alternative way to do this.

Also if you are working with TFS you might find this tool useful

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a6b04ebd-e025-4c90-b238-72b48f0dfbd2

Comment: In this moment we need to use both studios, because other stuff are set up for vs 2013